# Convert MySql database records to XML in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP script is calling MySQL and getting bunch of records. Is there a function/library in PHP that converts SQL database records into XML?  Something like `myDBRecords.ToXML()`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like [XML_Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer). It will take just about any PHP data structure and return you some XML.

Answer (score 0):

The command line allows to do

```
shell> mysql --xml -uroot -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'"
```

I don't know if is possible replicate this behavior on SELECT statement

More information in:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml

Other way to do is using a custom class, an example:

http://px.sklar.com/code.html/id=229